# Can't figure out why divs are uneven and don't fill page

Tags: css, flexbox

https://zmc27.github.io/resumetemp/
Coder-in-training here. If you check out my site and use the horizontal scroller, you'll notice that the "My Work" div extends further out than the others,  leaving an awkward white gap on the side of the page; I'm trying to figure out why this is happening and how to fix it. I've also been having trouble trying to get the flexbox column centered (these two issues could be related). Any help will be much appreciated!

```css
.page3 {
    background-image: linear-gradient(#EDE4E0, #C8DBBE) ;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0%;
    margin: -20;
    
}
.fit{
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    object-fit: cover;
    border: double;
    
}

.work{
    display:flex;
    gap:30px;
    padding-bottom: 70px ;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    
}
.worktxt{
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; 
    font-size: 50px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-top: 70px;
    padding-bottom: 70px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    letter-spacing: 3;
    
    color: 61764B;
}
p{
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
 <section class="container3">
            <div class="page3">
                <div class="page3title">
                    <h2 class="worktxt">My Work</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="work">
                <div class="boxes">
                    <a href="/11.3 TinDog Project/index.html"><img  class= "fit" src="./assets/tindog.png"></a>
                    <h3 class="workheader"> Tindog </h3>
                    <p>A class project built using bootstrap.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="boxes">
                    <a href="/10.3 Mondrian Project/index.html"><img class= "fit" src="./assets/mondrian.png"></a>
                    <h3 class="workheader">Mondrian Painting</h3>
                    <p>A class project that is constructed entirely by CSS Grid.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="boxes">
                    <a href="/Capstone 2/index.html"><img class= "fit" src="./assets/portfolio.png"></a>
                    <h3 class="workheader">Portfolio</h3>
                    <p>My personal project designed using HTML and CSS.</p>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Simply trying to make the website look aligned. If any more info is needed LMK.

Comment: The whitespace at the bottom is caused by the default margin on the `h4`. Not sure what you're talking about regarding the divs. But you haven't followed the rules for posting here, so unless you post some demo code of what you're trying to achieve, your post will be closed.

Comment: thanks, I've edited the post to better articulate the issue.

Comment: Your CSS is invalid. Run it through the validator and fix your errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your *My Work* div is extending out beyond the edge of the page because you've got `margin: -20` in the `.page3` declaration. Remove that and it won't overflow.

I'm assuming you also want to remove the whitespace between the `section` elements? It's the margins on the `h2` and `h3` elements that is causing those. Specifically, the `h3` containing "To learn about me, my experience, and my proficiencies, click the photo!" and the `h2` containing "Get in touch".

To centre your flexbox items, add `justify-content: center;` to your `.work` declaration.

BTW, before you post HTML or CSS here, it's always worth validating your code first.

- [W3C CSS Validation Service](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input)
- [W3C Markup Validation Service](https://validator.w3.org/)

Your CSS has a few validation errors, and although these aren't the cause of your problem, they might have provided a clue.

[image: Three CSS validation errors]

Hope that help. Welcome to the site. :)

Comment: The CSS is invalid with what he used in the first place and the question should be closed for that reason.

Comment: It may have been invalid, but HTML and CSS are fault tolerant by design. It's beside the point that it is invalid - it "worked" and therefore caused the problem. Even experienced authors get tripped up by such errors. But I'll update my answer to include a link to the CSS validator.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use justify-content: center; and justify-items: center; properties with flex layout for the work div section. and also given a width for the div word same as other sections.

```
.page3 {
    background-image: linear-gradient(#EDE4E0, #C8DBBE);
    position: relative;
    margin: -20 -0 -20 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    justify-content: center;
    justify-items: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Please try this solution. And learn more about flex layout in CSS. Ad the issue was you have given padding top,left,right and bottom. that's why you face that issue.